# Parametric Vector Form and Bases of Eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given the matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 3 \\
-3 & -5 & -3 \\
3 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

with eigenvalues 1, -2 and -2, find the bases of the eigenspaces. I use the characteristic equation (with eigenvalue 1) to create the matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 3 & 3 \\
-3 & -6 & -3 \\
3 & 3 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

which row reduces to

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now comes the confusion. The book gives the vector $$(1,-1,1)^T$$ as a basis for the eigenvalue 1. However, it seems to me that the parameterization should be $$ x = x_2(-1,1,0)^T + x_3(0, -1, 1)^T $$
What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you subtracted your eigenvalue of 1 and row reduced, you get the following matrix:

\begin{matrix}
 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}

A couple of things. First, this matrix can be reduced further. Replacing the first row with the first row minus the second row gives you :

\begin{matrix}
 1 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 1 &  1  \\
 0 & 0 &  0
\end{matrix}

Secondly, this matrix only has a one-dimensional null space. However, your solution has a two dimensional null space (set $x_2=0$, $x_3=1$ for the first; $x_2=1$, $x_3=0$ for the other). So I'll just say that that is where your error lies.

Finally, if you're ever unsure whether or not you have an eigenvector, you can always just plug it into your matrix and see if its an eigenvector corresponding to your eigenvalue or not.

After plugging your solutions in, I find that they are eigenvalues, but they are not the eigenvectors corresponding to 1. They correspond to your other two eigenvalues...